# Powershell script several issues

Tags: powershell, script

Some questions about a script I want to create. It's just the start. I will add other commands. I already tried to find all my answers via Google and many examples but the information you get is so overwhelming. Everyone seems to have his own solution and when I try it fails.

```
# This script is made to retrieve important information of a system running Windows. 

###############################
#Info where to drop information
###############################

$FilePath = "c:\tmp\SysNetInfo\" #location where you will find text file with information
$FileName = "SysNetInfo.txt" #name of my output file

########################
#Starting gathering info
########################

Read-Host 'This script is gathering some useful information from your system.'
Read-Host -Prompt "Press any key to continue"

# Get Ipv4 information: 
(gwmi Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | ? {$_.IPAddress -ne $null}).IPAddress
(gwmi Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | ? {$_.IPAddress -ne $null}).DefaultIPGateway
Out-File $FilePath\$FileName
```

Questions:

1. `Read-Host 'This script is gathering some useful information from your system.'`  I would like that my code continues to the next line. Instead it stops and needs user action. It's on the line afther this one that I request user interaction. I could easily skip this part and delete it but I would like to know the answer to my question.
2. I try to put the result of my commands in a text file. First I just used `Out-File C:\tmp\SysNetInfo\SysNetInfo.txt` (and it failed because it just gave me the default gateway) but I would like to use my variables FilePath and FileName.

Update:

Question 1 solved by David.

Question 2 - I get this error:

[image]

!!! Don't look for line 25. My original script has some comments that I didn't add in this post.

Comment: 1/ should that be `write-host`?

Comment: 2/ [Out-File (Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility) - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-7.2) shows the correct way to use `out-file`

Comment: Yes, thanks! Read-Host on first line and Write-Host on second. That's how it is now and it seems to do what I expect.

Comment: Thanks for the link David. I came across this one but it didn't really helped me. I will read it again.

Comment: Your script is expecting two user inputs because you call Read-Host twice. If you only want one, prompt, only call it once. Questions being closed due to typographical errors is a thing on Super User as well as Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

For #2:

Most likely you didn't create the directory `SysNetInfo` under `c:\tmp`. **PowerShell** file writing commaands will create the file but not the directory/directories.

Use something like:

```
If ( -not (Test-Path $FilePath) ) {
    mkdir $FilePath -Force
}
```

before any attempt to write to your file.

Though you have one possible solution for #1, another option is to have all your text as the prompt for `Read-Host`. Here-strings are one way to create multi-line strings:

```
$MyPrompt = @'
This script is gathering some useful information from your system.

PRess any key to continue...
'@
Read-Host $MyPrompt
....
```

Comment: $MyPrompt helped me a lot. I changed the script.
Also the first part of your answer was correct. It creates a folder now. My file remains empty though. I will have a look today what I do wrong.

Comment: @maxim You are not piping any information into the Out-File function. It is empty the way you are doing it. I would recommend using the powershell cmdlet for finding ipv4 info and doing it one command. Try replacing the entire "get ipv4 infomation block with this one liner: `Get-NetIPConfiguration | Select InterfaceAlias,IPv4Address,IPv4DefaultGateway | Out-File $FilePath\$FileName`

Comment: @Narzard: Thanks for jumping in, my **PowerShell** knowledge/experience is limited to a standalone laptop environment, so little familarity with network-related cmdlets.